# Why Method onClick(View v) has View type parameter?

Tags: java, android

The `onClick(View v)` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` methods are related to the motion of our fingers which can be recognized as an event in the device. So If I apply above logic, the `onClick(View v)` method and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method both have to receive the `MotionEvent` type parameter.

But why does the `onClick(View v)` method has the `View` type parameter?

Answer (score 2):

`onClick(View v)`

Here, parameter `v` stands for the `View` that was clicked.
I don't understand why you are confused about this. You are passing the `View` that was clicked inside the method and all your actions are written inside this method. 
You can check the id of the clicked view and assign actions like

```
  if(v.getId() == R.id.Button){
        // Write your code for button click here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the `View v` that was clicked.

[Android View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Whener you are clicking any button , switch, radio button you are clicking a view as per android implementation . These above mentioned controls are called views . Your screen may have multiple views , therefore to know which view is actually clicked you have to have a way which is provided by View parameter . You can use getId method and identify which view os clicked and perform actions accordingly.